# Enabling Wireguard tunnel through ADB shell

Tags: adb, vpn

I'm trying to enable and disable Wireguard tunnels through the ADB shell.

I can see the followings actions and receivers are available :

```
adb:# dumpsys package com.wireguard.android
...
Receiver Resolver Table:
  Non-Data Actions:
      com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP:
        4166aa1 com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver filter 631a6bf
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.REFRESH_TUNNEL_STATES"
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP"
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_DOWN"
      com.wireguard.android.action.REFRESH_TUNNEL_STATES:
        4166aa1 com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver filter 631a6bf
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.REFRESH_TUNNEL_STATES"
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP"
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_DOWN"
      com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_DOWN:
        4166aa1 com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver filter 631a6bf
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.REFRESH_TUNNEL_STATES"
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP"
          Action: "com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_DOWN"
      android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED:
        4f4cb74 com.wireguard.android/.BootShutdownReceiver filter 426c4de
          Action: "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"
          Action: "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
      android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN:
        4f4cb74 com.wireguard.android/.BootShutdownReceiver filter 426c4de
          Action: "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"
          Action: "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"
...
```

Looking at [the package's sourcecode](https://github.com/WireGuard/wireguard-android/blob/aaf8b3205272a2b811df7b400f7c0b6ab9f69d39/ui/src/main/java/com/wireguard/android/model/TunnelManager.kt#L213-L240), I see that `com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver` asks for the name of the tunnel to enable/disable to be passed as an extra string :

```
 val tunnelName = intent.getStringExtra("tunnel") ?: return@launch
 val tunnels = manager.getTunnels()
 val tunnel = tunnels[tunnelName] ?: return@launch
```

So I tried two different versions of the same command to enable a tunnel named `my-tunnel` :

```
adb:# am broadcast -a com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP -e tunnel my-tunnel
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP flg=0x400000 (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
# am broadcast -a com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP -e tunnel my-tunnel -n com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver                                                    
Broadcasting: Intent { act=com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP flg=0x400000 cmp=com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

But after checking on my phone `my-tunnel` is still disabled.

What am I missing ? Note that I'm pretty new to using ADB commands so it might be something obvious.

Comment: When calling a Intent/Broadcast via adb and `am` then actual code is executed asynchronously, therefore you never get an result. Effectively this means the result code you see is meaningless.

Comment: Good to know ! I edited my question in accordance.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most reliable way that I have found:

```
am broadcast -a com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_UP -n 'com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver' -e tunnel <tunnel_name>
am broadcast -a com.wireguard.android.action.SET_TUNNEL_DOWN -n 'com.wireguard.android/.model.TunnelManager$IntentReceiver' -e tunnel <tunnel_name>
```

Notes:

- This only works if adb has root rights.
- You need to enable "Allow remote control apps" under "Advanced" in the settings of the WireGuard app.
- If you also want this to work when the WireGuard app is not running, you need to disable background battery optimizations for the app.